# Porque o linux tem uma ISO para cada arquitetura de processador?

Tags: linux, arquitetura-computadores

Olá, gostaria de entender porque o Linux tem várias `ISO's` para cada tipo de CPU (AMD64, i386, etc..), porque o Windows não precisa disso, e como é feita a compilação para cada tipo de arquitetura.

Se possível, passem links que tenham isso mais a fundo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Gostaria de entender porque o Linux tem várias ISO's para cada tipo de CPU (amd64, i386, etc..) e porque o Windows não precisa disso?

Porque a arquitetura do processador influencia em toda a compilação do Kernel e dos aplicativos que acompanham a distribuição Linux. Qualquer sistema operacional é desta forma.

Cada processador possui seu próprio conjunto de instruções. Cada conjunto de instruções exige que o *assembly* do sistema operacional seja montado de uma forma diferente.

O Windows não escapa disso. Ao instalar, o instalador detecta a arquitetura do processador antes de iniciar e instala o kernel mais adequado ao processador em questão.

## E como compila isso para cada tipo de arquitetura?

No caso do Linux, o GCC por padrão compila em 32 bits, mas adicionando a flag `-m64` fará o compilador realizar uma compilação em 64 bits. [O GCC também suporta *cross-compiling*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/i386-and-x86-64-Options.html) (compilação tanto para 32 bits quanto para 64 bits, mas apenas a nível de bibliotecas).

Há, ainda, a opção de selecionar outras arquiteturas. [A lista de arquiteturas suportadas pelo GCC está aqui](https://gcc.gnu.org/backends.html).

Comment: O Windows possui sim várias ISOs para arquiteturas diferentes.

Comment: A última vez que usei uma dessas foi dum update de Vista pro 7. Depois nunca mais vi. É uma mídia só com várias edições dentro.

Comment: Antigamente cabiam os binários de várias arquiteturas em uma única mídia. Hoje isso já não é possível em um DVD. Além disso, antigamente a parcela do x86-32 que precisava ser enviada junto com o x86-64 era muito maior do que a atual. Algumas distribuições de Linux (como o Fedora) irão inclusive remover o suporte a arquitetura x86-32.

Comment: Aliás, hoje em dia tá cada vez mais difícil ver "mídias", mesmo as em DVD. Meu notebook, por exemplo, nem drive de DVD tem mais.

Answer (score 6):

Vou ser bem breve: <kbd>AMD64</kbd> são para processadores de `64 bits`, e leva o nome da AMD porque ela fez primeiro; <kbd>i386</kbd> são para os processadores `32 bits`, e leva o `i` de Intel porque ela fez primeiro. ;)

**Um pouco de história:**

- **Intel**

<kbd>x86</kbd> ou <kbd>80x86</kbd> são nomes genéricos dados à família de processadores baseados no <kbd>Intel 8086</kbd>, da Intel Corporation.

A arquitetura é chamada <kbd>x86</kbd> porque os primeiros processadores desta família eram identificados somente por números terminados com a sequência "86": o 8086, o 80**186**, o 80**286**, o 80**386** e o 80**486**.

Como **não** se pode ter uma **marca registrada sobre números**,  a Intel e a maior parte de seus competidores começaram a usar nomes que pudessem ser registrados como marca, como **Pentium** para as gerações de processadores posteriores, mas a antiga nomenclatura já tinha forjado um termo para toda a família: o tal **<kbd>x86</kbd>**.

- **Amd**

**<kbd>AMD64</kbd>**, **<kbd>x64</kbd>** ou **<kbd>x86-64</kbd>**, são nomes genéricos dados à família de processadores baseados na tecnologia de **64 bit**, utilizada pelos processadores da **AMD** e da **Intel**.

O **<kbd>x86-64</kbd>** foi desenhado pela empresa Advanced Micro Devices (AMD), que o renomeou **<kbd>AMD64</kbd>**. A Intel foi obrigada a seguir o exemplo, introduzindo modificações já no Pentium 4, e assim lançou o chamado <kbd>Intel64</kbd>, que é quase idêntico ao <kbd>AMD64</kbd>.

> https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD64
>
> https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86

Respondendo de forma mais direta a sua pergunta, temos o `ISO 32bits` e o `ISO 64bits`, tanto para SO Windows quanto para SO Linux (viu como o windows também precisa "disso").Quando for ISO <kbd>AMD64</kbd> irá instalar para processadores `64bits` tanto Intel quando AMD (vide a explicação acima), e quando for <kbd>i386</kbd> irá instalar `32bits` - vide a explicação acima. :)

Comment: por fim ficou mais longa que a do Cigano... mas pelo menos esta bem explicadinho